How to excute a select query with bind parameter in Oracle
I'm using PL Sql develop as the editor, I create a new query window  and execute with flow sql
declare 
  my_a number := 1
  ;
Begin
  select :my_a as "a" from dual;

END;

Then, it shows an error

ORA-01008: not all variables bound

I'm wondering that can oracle execute a sql block with bind variables that not defined inside a view/function/stored procedure

I'm familiar with SqlServer,  and in SqlSerer I can do this (in SSMS or navicate)
declare @name nvarchar(50) = 'john'

select * from table t where t.name = @name 


and now with ORACLE (in PL/SQL DEVElOP or navicate ) , I can only do this

select * from table where t.name = 'john'

but I use follow code when develop a web app
var result = sqlSugar.SqlQuery("select * from table where t.name = :name", new { name = 'john' })


// it will log the sql and parameter
//  select * from table where t.name = :name
//  name varchar(2) = 'john'

(now ,I change the log  to log as select * from table where t.name = 'john' , but it hard to debug the sql where there too much column when insert)

You cannot run SELECT inside of a Block BEGIN END;

@VahramDanielyan  is there anyway that I can run sql like Sql Server   eg. ```
declare @v nvarchar(40) = 'hello'
select @v as value


You are using PL/SQL so if you define a variable my_a you reference it without colon.
Additionally if use select a value in PL/SQL  you must use a into clause.
Here a possible example of that what you wanted - the script return 1 as a result.
declare 
  my_a number := 1;
  my_b number;
Begin
  select  my_a as "a" into my_b from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(my_b);
END;
/


Your question has already been answered (and all answers up to this point are correct and useful).
Let me just add a clarification. You have two types of variables:

Pl/SQL variables, introduced by a DECLARE keyword and valid inside the associated block (DECLARE ... BEGIN ... END). These variables aren't preceded by the :. They're just understood by the PL/SQL engine based on context.

Bind variables, which are part of the "host" environment (the C code on a Pro-C program, the SQL-Plus environment, etc). These use the form :variable, because the engine doesn't know them beforehand and has to reference the host environment. In SQL-Plus, you can create a bind variable using the VARIABLE keyword (outside a PL/SQL block, because, as I said, there are not part of PL/SQL).


Added. Bind variables, as they don't depend on PL/SQL, can also be used with plain "stand-alone" SQL: SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE DUMMY = :var (provided you created var on the host environment).

I'm trying to execute the sql from some log ,  and the sql has bind variables ,     (provided you created var on the host environment)  does that means I can not execute the sql  with bind variable in PL/Sql Develop's Sql editor

That's because the application that logged the statement, before trying to run it, defined the host variable. Did you try the SELECT alone, with the :my_a but without the enclosing DECLARE..BEGIN..END? In your case, as it's an input variable, SQL*Developer should ask you for its value.

In fact, your SELECT statement is just saying "Give whatever I stored in the variable, under a header labeled "a" (from a dummy table with just one record)".


Did you try the SELECT alone
yes,    but pl sql develop  report error ORA-01008: not all variables bound ,  the sql I use select :abc from dual


Try the "Execute Statement" command/icon, not "Run Script".

there is no "Execute Statement" , but only a Execute button.  and I start think it may be impossible to execute a  sql with defined "bind varaiables" in "PL/SQL Develop"

In a SQL developer "worksheet" (the place where you enter your code), there is an icon/button with just a green "play" triangle, on the far left of the toolbar. Use this one (and not the one on its right). Alternatively, you may select the entire line/code and press Control+Enter.

I think we might talking different software ,  I also try "navicate" ， I also can not find a way to execute a sql query with "bind variables"

I was talking about Oracle's own "SQL Developer". You may try it. Anyway, you need to provide the value for the bind variable to the tool you're using, which will provide it to the server (along with the statement itself). Otherwise, the server will report the ORA-01008.

We're assuming you really need to use a bind variable. But if you're just concerned for the result of the query, you can just replace the :my_a with a plain 1 or whatever you want.


you declared a variable (my_a)
no problem in selecting it in an anonymous PL/SQL block, but its select then requires an into clause (line #6)

for that purpose, create a new variable (such as l_var in my example, line #3))


I chose to display it (line #9); you'd do whatever you want with it


SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    my_a  number := 1  ;
  3    l_var number;
  4  Begin
  5    select my_a as "a"
  6    into l_var
  7    from dual;
  8
  9    dbms_output.put_line('value = ' || l_var);
 10  END;
 11  /
value = 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>


If you want to use BIND variable you should define a SELECT statement as REFCURSOS like:
set serveroutput on
variable my_query refcursor
declare 
  my_a number := 1;
Begin
  open :my_query for
    select my_a as "a" from dual;
END;
/
print my_query

Otherwise if you want to insert a input variable you can run like:
select &1 as a from dual

Remember that two words must go between quotation mark '
